# Hessian in an orthonormal frame

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, tensors

Let $\{E_i\}$ be an orthonormal frame. I am trying to express the Hessian of a function $f$ as a (0,2)-tensor in terms of the tensor product of the dual coframe $\{\Theta^i\}$. We first compute the gradient of $f$ as
$$\left<\nabla f, E_k\right>=E_kf \implies \nabla f=\sum_k (E_kf)E_k.$$
Then, the components of the Hessian are computed as
\begin{align*} 
\nabla^2 f(E_i,E_j)&:=\left<\nabla_{E_i}\nabla f,E_j\right>\\
&=\left<\nabla_{E_i} \sum_k (E_kf)E_k,E_j\right>\\
&=\sum_k\left<(E_iE_k f)E_k+(E_kf)\nabla_{E_i}E_k,E_j\right>\\
&=E_iE_jf+\sum_{k,l}\left<(E_kf)\omega_{lk}(E_i)E_l,E_j\right>\\
&=E_iE_jf+\sum_k(E_kf)\omega_{jk}(E_i)\\
&=\sum_k(E_kE_jf)\Theta_k(E_i)+\sum_k (E_kf)\omega_{jk}(E_i)
\end{align*}
This expresses the $\nabla^2 f(-,E_j)$ as a $(0,1)$-tensor, namely
$$\nabla^2 f(-,E_j)=\sum_k(E_kE_jf)\Theta_k+(E_kf)\omega_{jk}.$$
Is it correct to say the $(0,2)$ version is
$$\nabla^2 f= \sum_{k,l}(E_kE_lf)\Theta_k\otimes \Theta_l+(E_kf)\omega_{lk}\otimes \Theta_l?$$
Is so, is there any nice way to express this purely in terms of $\Theta_l\otimes \Theta_k$? That is, do the connection 1-forms admit any nice expression in terms of the coframe?

Comment: No. If they did, we’d never use the connection $1$-forms. The connection $1$-forms are essentially the covariant derivatives of the orthonormal frame, $$ \nabla_XE_k = E_j\langle \omega^j_k, X\rangle$$

Comment: You have already done the best you could going from $$\nabla^2f = \sum_{i,j=1}^n \left(E_i(E_j(f)) - \sum_{k=1}^n \omega_{kj}(E_i)E_k(f)\right)\Theta_i\otimes\Theta_j,$$which is [just linear algebra (p. 10)](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/terekcouto.1/texts/tensors.pdf), to your last expression.